# Mock classes with traits

Tags: scala, mocking, traits

Is there any library that provides tools for mocking classes with traits (both can be statefull)?

Simplified example:

```
trait T {
  var xx: List[Int] = List[Int]()
  def t(x: Int) {
    xx ::= x    //throws NPE, xx == null, even after implicit initialization
  }
}

class A extends T {
}

class Testable(a: A) {
  def bar() {
    a.t(2)
  }
}

@Test def testFoo() {
  val a: A = mock[A]
  val testable = new Testable(a)
  testable.bar()
  verify(a).t(2)
}
```

Comment: So Mockito doesn't work?

Comment: @Jens Schauder , example provided. For me, it seems like there is some issue with mocking by mockito.

Answer (score 5):

Paul Butcher has been working on Borachio, a Scala mocking library. It supports mocking of traits, classes, functions and objects. See the following blogs for more information:

http://www.paulbutcher.com/2011/02/announcing-borachio-native-scala-mocking/
http://www.paulbutcher.com/2011/07/power-mocking-in-scala-with-borachio/

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help me. Static method (Java) support only in TODO list (by July 5, 2011)

Comment: I continue to work on it :-) You're right that I haven't yet got Java static method support in place, but singleton/companion objects have been supported in the typesafemocks branch (described in Arjan's second link above) for a while. This is still under development, so you should certainly treat with caution, but it does work :-)

Comment: @Paul Butcher -  So, can I test classes with traits like in provided example with any version/snapshot of Borachio?

Comment: There is a 2.0-SNAPSHOT published on [scala-tools](http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/com/borachio/), and the blog post above gives an example of using this. It's slightly out of date, however, so you might be better off using the head of the typesafemocks branch. The documentation leaves a lot to be desired, I know, but please do let me know if you hit any issues and I'll do my best to help.

Answer (score 2):

Well ... I don't have an answer, but I think I can offer a hint at where the problem is coming from. I took a look at A.class and found this (de.schauderhaft.testen is the package I used):

```
  // Method descriptor #21 (I)V
  // Stack: 2, Locals: 2
  public bridge void t(int x);
    0  aload_0 [this]
    1  iload_1 [x]
    2  invokestatic de.schauderhaft.testen.T$class.t(de.schauderhaft.testen.T, int) : void [26]
    5  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 13]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 6] local: this index: 0 type: de.schauderhaft.testen.A
        [pc: 0, pc: 6] local: x index: 1 type: int
```

I'm no byte code expert but this

```
2  invokestatic de.schauderhaft.testen.T$class.t(de.schauderhaft.testen.T, int) : void [26]
```

looks like the call to t(Int) is actually a called to a static method and you can't mock static methods. PowerMock would help, but probably ugly to use.

Comment: Thanks, I should try PowerMock.

Answer (score 1):

I just released [ScalaMock](http://scalamock.org/) 2.0. As well as functions and interfaces, ScalaMock can mock:

- Classes
- Singleton and companion objects (static methods)
- Object creation (constructor invocation)
- Classes with private constructors
- Final classes and classes with final methods
- Operators (methods with symbolic names)
- Overloaded methods

Comment: Thanks for informing. I would try.